# Centos: Merge directories while removing a common subdirectory in all subs

Tags: file, merge, directory, centos, structure

Very weird and specific question I know but would save me a big headache.

Is it possible to merge directories while removing a specific sub in each sub but keeping all files? Example

I have

```
/first/1/files/1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg
/first/2/files/1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg
```

I also have

```
/second/1/3.jpg, 4.jpg, 5.jpg
/second/2/3.jpg, 4.jpg, 5.jpg
```

I want to merge `/first` into `/second` while also removing the inbetween `/files/` directory in `/first` but keeping all the jpgs.  On top of that, I don't want 3.jpg to be overwritten in `/second/`

Comment: Any common files you want to keep the copy of from `second`?

Comment: Yes, if possible, if they have overwrite that's not a big deal as they are supposed to be the same file I'm just not 100%

Answer (score 1):

If timestamps don't matter then you could do something like:

```
find /second -name '*.jpg' -exec touch +
for fdir in /first/*/files; do
    sdir=${fdir%/files};
    sdir=${sdir#/tmp/first};
    sdir=/tmp/second${sdir};
    cp -u "$fdir/"* "$sdir/";
done
```

though that's not exactly what I'd call a good solution.

You could also do this manually testing for existing files while looping and copying like this:

```
for ffile in /first/*/files/*.jpg; do
    # Expand the variable and delete '/files'
    sfile=${ffile/\/files}
    # Expand the variable and remove the '/first' prefix
    sfile=${sfile#/tmp/first}
    # Prepend the new '/second' direcory.
    sfile=/second${sfile}
    # If the exist do nothing. It if doesn't then copy.
    [ -f "$sfile" ] || cp -u "$ffile" "$sfile"
done
```

I feel like there is probably a clever way to do this with rsync or cpio but I don't know what that is.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm a little nervous to try this because I have no idea what I'm doing loops in the command line.

Comment: Stick `echo` before the `cp` in each script `echo cp ....` and it is safe to run as a test. It'll output the commands it would have otherwise run. That's the only thing that actually *does* anything.

Comment: Alternatively, if the data allows for it make a copy/backup before running it. You can also add `set -x` to the top of the script to get the shell to list each command it runs as it runs it.